# Python: Is there a way to scrape the abstract text from the articles within each of the href links on a search-results-page of an online database?

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I input search-terms into the search-bar of an online database (pubmed- a database for scientific articles) I get a list of that links to articles that result from the search. I want to click on each of the links, open each in a new tab-window and copy the text from the abstract (summary-article) so that I can paste each one into a file.

I recently found out that it might be a lot more useful to do this with python. I am aware that I can scrape the url-data as follows:

```
import requests
import bs4

root_url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed'
index_url = root_url + '/?term=%28histone%29+AND+%28chromatin%29+AND+%28hESC%29'

def get_video_page_urls():
    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.rprt a[href^=/pubmed]')]

print(get_video_page_urls())

['/pubmed/27939217', '/pubmed?linkname=pubmed_pubmed&from_uid=27939217'..... etc.
```

My question is: can collect the abstract-text (similarly to clicking into the link and copy-pasting the text) from each of the href links that result from the search, and subsequently analyse them?

Initially, I tried:

```
import requests
r=requests.get('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/term=%28histone%29+AND+%28chromatin%29+AND+%28hESC%29')
r.content
```

The output of this results in all the html text that makes the search-results page but I cannot seem to find a distinct pattern that specifies the text that is linked to by each of the hrefs. So I'm wondering how I can isolate text that is on a different page...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work on this more. This is what I have got:

```
url="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28034892"
r = requests.get(url)
print BeautifulSoup(r.content).select('div.abstr')[0].prettify()
```

To get all the abstracts from those urls you can use this:

```
for a in set(get_video_page_urls()):
    if len(a)<40:
        url="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov" + a
        r = requests.get(url)
        print BeautifulSoup(r.content).select('div.abstr')[0].prettify()
```

Instead of printing it to screen you can save it to some file.

Answer (score 3):

Soup is designed to handle poorly structured pages heuristically. For cleaner pages and straightforward data scraping like this, I prefer LXML with  Xpath calls. To find the Xpaths of the on-page content you're after, either use the Inspect feature of your browser or a browser plugin like XPath Helper Wizard.

This will dump out the first 10 results and abstracts to a CSV.

Update, November, 2023:

I was just revisiting this; the page structure has changed, the code below works now. However, >3 hits/sec gets you kicked out; register for the NCBI API key to do up to 10/sec.
Also, the dispmax query parameter to show more results is gone, and the results are paginated, they give you 10 results per page, so you can either use Selenium to click the button, which gives you a long scrolling page, or loop the pages: (1, no parameter), &page=2, &page=3, etc. Also, if there is only one result, it takes you directly to that page.

You can also use the NCBI EUtilies per their docs
https://ncbiinsights.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2022/11/22/updated-pubmed-eutilities-live/
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499
and the metapub python package
https://pypi.org/project/metapub/

```
import unicodecsv as csv
from lxml import html, etree
import lxml.html.clean
import requests
CSV_File = 'PubMed_Abstracts.csv'
with open(CSV_File, 'ab') as csv_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
    writer.writerow(['Search_Term', 'Result', 'Title', 'Abstract', 'PMID', 'PubMed URL', 'PMCID', 'PMC URL', 'DOI', 'DOI URL'])

Search_Terms = ['((histone)%20AND%20chromatin)%20AND%20ESC', 'ssoadvanced']
#Search_Terms = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('URLs.txt')]
m = len(Search_Terms)
import time
t = time.time()
rS = 1
for Search_Term in Search_Terms:
    Search_URL = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=' + Search_Term
    Search_Page = requests.get(Search_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(Search_Page.content)
    Multi_Results = tree.xpath('//div[@class="results-amount"]/h3/span/text()')
    if Multi_Results:
        Num_Results = int(''.join(Multi_Results))
        Pub_Results = tree.xpath('//a[@class="docsum-title"]')
        rR = 1
        for count, Pub_Result in enumerate(Pub_Results):
            Result_Num = count + 1
            Pub_Title = ' '.join(Pub_Result.text_content().split())
            PMID = Pub_Result.get('href').replace('/','')
            PubMed_URL = 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/' + PMID
            Pub_Page = requests.get(PubMed_URL)
            Pub_Tree = html.fromstring(Pub_Page.content)
            Abstract = Pub_Tree.xpath('//div[@id="eng-abstract"]/p')
            for p in Abstract:
                p.addprevious(etree.XML('<p></p>'))
                h2s = p.xpath('strong|b')
                for h2 in h2s:
                        h2.addprevious(etree.XML('<p></p>'))
                        h2.drop_tag()
            text_cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(allow_tags='p')
            for x in Abstract:
                text_cleaner.clean_html(x)
            
            Abstract_text = ''.join([s for s in ' '.join([x.text_content() for x in Abstract]).strip().splitlines(True) if s.strip()])
            PMC = Pub_Tree.xpath('//a[@class="id-link" and @data-ga-action="PMCID"]/text()')
            if PMC:
                PMCID = PMC[0].strip()
                PMC_URL = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/' + PMCID
            else:
                PMCID = PMC_URL = ''
            DOI = Pub_Tree.xpath('//a[@class="id-link" and @data-ga-action="DOI"]/text()')[0].strip()
            DOI_URL = 'https://doi.org/' + DOI
            with open(CSV_File, 'ab') as csv_out:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_out, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
                writer.writerow([Search_Term, Result_Num, Pub_Title, Abstract_text, PMID, PubMed_URL, PMCID, PMC_URL, DOI, DOI_URL])
    else:
        Num_Results = 1
        Pub_Title = tree.xpath('//h1/text()')[0].strip()
        PMID = tree.xpath('//strong[@title="PubMed ID"]/text()')[0].strip()
        PubMed_URL = 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/' + PMID
        Abstract = tree.xpath('//div[@id="eng-abstract"]/p')
        for p in Abstract:
            p.addprevious(etree.XML('<p></p>'))
            h2s = p.xpath('strong|b')
            for h2 in h2s:
                    h2.addprevious(etree.XML('<p></p>'))
                    h2.drop_tag()
        
        text_cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(allow_tags='p')
        for x in Abstract:
            text_cleaner.clean_html(x)
        
        Abstract_text = ''.join([s for s in ' '.join([x.text_content() for x in Abstract]).strip().splitlines(True) if s.strip()])
        PMC = tree.xpath('//a[@class="id-link" and @data-ga-action="PMCID"]/text()')
        if PMC:
            PMCID = PMC[0].strip()
            PMC_URL = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/' + PMCID
        else:
            PMCID = PMC_URL = ''
        DOI = tree.xpath('//a[@class="id-link" and @data-ga-action="DOI"]/text()')[0].strip()
        DOI_URL = 'https://doi.org/' + DOI
        with open(CSV_File, 'ab') as csv_out:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_out, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
            writer.writerow([Search_Term, Result_Num, Pub_Title, Abstract_text, PMID, PubMed_URL, PMCID, PMC_URL, DOI, DOI_URL])        
        
        elapsed_time = time.time() - t
        print('\n', rR, 'of', Num_Results, 'Results;', rS, 'of', m, 'Search Terms: Elapsed Time', time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(elapsed_time)), '\n')
        rR += 1
    rS += 1
```